# JSON Response headers

Tags: php, json

The following headers seem to be recommended using when outputing JSON:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

What is the purpose of the Expires header when Cache-control is set to no-cache, must-revalidate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This resolves some browser and caching proxies issues.

It seems like there are some of these that do not understand some headers and/or are configured not to, so it is just a workaround trying to be compatible with a little more of the end users' browser and caching proxies in the middle.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Is there any reason for doing this: header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); header('Expires: '.date('r', time()+(86400*365)); (http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/190001/)?

Comment: @seberik - my guess is that the **+** /plus/ is a typo and was supposed to be a **-** /minus/.

Answer (score 0):

The first two headers prevent the browser from caching the response (a problem with IE and GET requests) and the third sets the correct MIME type for JSON.